# Button should remain disabled after the page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i applied disability for some time on submit button....after some time its gets enabled..i.e. after 15sec....bt if i am refreshing the page then the button gets enabled...the button lost the diable time and gets enable...please help me..

```js
$(window).load(function(){
var enableSubmit = function(ele) {
    $(ele).removeAttr("disabled");
}

$("#submit").click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function() { enableSubmit(that) }, 15000);
});
}); 


    var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
input[disabled] {
 background-color:#FF6347;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn" />
```

Comment: Code does not work, please include jQuery.

Comment: You are refreshing the page making it a fresh start, your disabling and timers don't survive the page reload.

Comment: You need to write server side code for this. Store the value in cookie. Check the cookie value every time you reload the page and disable it

Comment: backend is not needed, but use a cookie or localStorage would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is use browser localstorage (HTML5 feature) to store button state in it and on page load just get that state from localstorage and assign it to button using JS.
For using localstorage , you can get help on this link :
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp.

In your submit function :

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    localStorage.setItem("button-state", 'true');
    setTimeout(function() {     $("#submit").attr('disabled',true);}, 15000);
});
```

And inside Window onload at beginning of code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var buttonState=Boolean(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
   $("#submit").attr('disabled',buttonState);
});
```

Comment: (don't forget to clear the "button-state" in the timeout and re-start the timeout on load)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little more elaborated workaround, which allows you to calculate exactly the desired time. I think that the code explains for itself, otherwise just ask. Also, you can adapt it to your needs. [See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxbjnee1/).

*Note: you'll find the methods for cookies in the jsfiddle.*

```
$(function(){
    Program.Init();
});

var Program = {

    Init: function(){
        this.$target = $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
        this.EnableSubmit();
        this.EventHandler();
    },

    EnableSubmit: function(){
        var value = this.Cookies.Get('submit_button');
        var now = Date.now();
        if( !value ) {
            this.$target.removeAttr("disabled");
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(function() { Program.EnableSubmit(); }, value - now);
    },

    Submit: function(){
        this.$target.attr("disabled", true);
        this.Cookies.Set('submit_button', Date.now() + 15000, 0.25, { expire_in: 'minutes' });
        setTimeout(function() { Program.EnableSubmit(); }, 15000);
    },

    EventHandler: function(){
        this.$target.on('click', function(){ Program.Submit(); });
    }

};
```